# custom comparator in lower_bound() stl function in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, stl

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
bool compare(int a,int b){
    cout<<a<<" "<<b<<endl;
    return a<=b;
}

int main()
{    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n]={1,2,5,10,50,100,200,500,2000};
    int money=100;
    int it =lower_bound(a,a+n,money,compare)-a;
    cout<<a[it];
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, I made a custom comparator for `lower_bound()`, so it is supposed to output 100 in the end (as in the lst compare 100 <=100 is true). But it gives the next index (200) as an output... why?

Comment: please post code as text not images. you comparator returns less than or equal, `std::lower_bound` expects less than

Comment: As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Hello, and welcome! Please don't share pictures of your code, but copy the code in the question (that's the reason why people voted to close your question in the first place). I did it for you this time, to show you how it can be done. For the record, I copied your code from https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1M04.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, just as Yadav said. You can also see cppreference about compare requirement:

comp    -   binary predicate which returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound